# How can I use BabelJS with Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an ASP.NET(4.5) site running with IIS(8) using C#(5) and I want to use the ES6 new features.

[*I'm already using*](http://jsbin.com/fonuromobu/1/edit?html,js,output) BabelJS for "transforming" the code . But this is done on the *client* side using `browser.js` :

(This is just an example. the JS content is on a separate file).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

class Test { //new feature
  test() {
    return "test";
  }
}

var test = new Test;

console.log(test.test()); // "test"
</script>
```

But that means that it *will take time* from when the page is fully downloaded by the client - until `browser.js` finishes to "translate" the code.

**Question:**

How can I make the server to yield an *already "converted" js code using babel*  so that when it reaches the client , it is already "translated" ?

Comment: Other the pre-transpiling?

Comment: @Amit I don't understand your comment. I 'm looking for some DLL or some `BabelJs.TransformCode()` alike  method.. Just like MARKDOWN has C#/.net convereters for  markdown code.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if your client side code is either dynamicly generated or otherwise impractical to transpile as part of the build process of your site. If your question is *how* to go through this build step, well, node?

Comment: @Amit assuming I have a cshtml/aspx page which has html with the code in my example . But I'm looking for a C# method / other solution -  that will transpill all the es6 code into useable JS. I'm not using node. I'm using IIS .

Comment: That's why I asked about the practicality of transpiling. If you're JS code is inlined in your CSHTML, you're in trouble as far as Babel goes (and I don't know what other tools there are for this). However, I'd strongly suggest you move any such code *out* of your CSHTML and into dedicated JS script files. It's a much better structure for your project to separate code from markup. Once you do that, you can use node as a build tool, it doesn't have to host your site.

Comment: @Amit Yes. that was just an example. of course I have separated JS files. But how can I make the following to work : " when I Build the project - create a new transpilled version of the desire Js file" ? (I mean - I don't want to go each time to NODE and rebuild the js file".

Comment: @RoyiNamir Visual Studio 2015 has support for Gulp. You can use [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) along with a Pre-Build trigger

Comment: @RGraham Oh:-) thank you. I'll have a look at this.